# AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'pygame'

Tags: python, pygame, attributeerror, pygame-surface

I am following a Python Programming tutorial entitled 'Python Crash Course, a hands on, project-based introduction to programming', and I have arrived at the section that taught me how to make an alien invasion game. here is the link to the book: https://nostarch.com/pythoncrashcourse2e/

when I ran the code (not that the game is not finished) an error occurred. here is my code:

```
import sys

import pygame

class Ship:
    "a class to manage ship"

    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        "initialize the ship and set its starting position."
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.pygame.freetype.get_rect()

        #load the ship image and get its rect. 
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/pixel_ship_yellow.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        #start the ship at the bottom of ze screen thign
        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom

    def blitme(self):
        "Draw the ship at its current location."
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

#yes yes yes yes yes yes
class settings:
    """ A class to store all settings for Alien Invasion. """

    def __init__(self):
        """ Initialize the game's settings. """
        # Screen settings
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

class Alien_Invasion:
    """ Overall class to manage game assets and behaviour. """

    def __init__(self):
        """ Initialize the game, and create game resources. """
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = settings()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
            (self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

        # Set the background color. 
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
        
        self.ship = Ship(self)

    def run_game(self):
        """ Start the main loop for the game. """
        # Watch for keyboard and mouse events. 
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

        # Redraw the screen during each pass through the loop. 
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
        self.ship.blitme()

        # Make the most recently drawn screen available.
        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Make a game instance, and run the game. 
    ai = Alien_Invasion()
    ai.run_game
```

I received this:

```
File "c:\Users\[___]\Downloads\assets\assets\Alien_invasion_vscode.py", line 67, in <module>
    ai = Alien_Invasion()
  File "c:\Users\[___]\Downloads\assets\assets\Alien_invasion_vscode.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.ship = Ship(self)
  File "c:\Users\[___]\Downloads\assets\assets\Alien_invasion_vscode.py", line 11, in __init__
    self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.pygame.freetype.get_rect()
AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'pygame'
```

i got the assets from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q-__8Xw9KTM after i lost my book and then i found it again.

my specs:
TEXT EDITOR: VISUAL STUDIO CODE
Electron: 12.0.13
Chrome: 89.0.4389.128
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 8.9.255.25-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19041
Windows 10 64-bit
language: PYTHON
download PYTHON in python.org (idk why i put this)

can anyone help me? thanks.

Comment: It is a typo. Most likely a copy/paste issue. `ai_game.screen.pygame.freetype.get_rect()` needs  to be `ai_game.screen.get_rect()`

Comment: use a debugger and inspect every parameter during execution

Answer (score 0):

Read the error message and correct the line of code:

<s>`self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.pygame.freetype.get_rect()`</s>

```py
self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()
```